# Can't push a new, blank git branch

Tags: git, branch

I was trying to make a new, blank branch in git... I tried the instructions here:

http://www.bitflop.com/document/116
and here:

http://schacon.github.com/gitbook/5_creating_new_empty_branches.html

They seemed to give the same result, it appeared to have made a new branch, but pushing the blank branch failed. (it always printed out something like `!rejected TEST->TEST non fastforward`).

Furthermore, Windows popped up a dialog saying that Git crashed. I upgraded from 1.7.11? to the latest 1.8 from the git site, with same results.

I also thought it odd that `git branch` didn't show the new branch name. Is this a known bug in git, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Define "Empty". Does your repository have zero commits in it?

Comment: I wanted to make an empty branch with no commits, not based on/branched off another branch.

Comment: How is the code in your upcoming branch related to what's already in the repository?

Comment: It's code for a similar software, it needs some parts of the master branch code, but in a different structure, and will never be merged back to master branch.

Comment: What's the benefit of having it in the same repository if you'll never merge between the branches? (You just want everyone be able to look at the history of the parallel product without downloading another one?) In other words, why not re-structure based on the last commit in the current repository, that way you preserve some amount of history?

Answer (score 0):

there's couple things to checkout here:

First, Git server will block every non-fast-forward branch pushed. This is to prevent data loss. To force it, you must add `--force` flag to the command `git push origin TEST --force`. **Careful: this will remove all unique commits contained in origin/TEST**, and eventually they'll be lost (in 6 months if I remember correctly). In your case, it looks like the branch `TEST` already exist on the server; is this the case and do you know why? (because you may not want to overwrite it if what the branch contain is valuable)

Also, as you've been creating a new branch by basically removing history, you should make sure you have at least one initial commit in your branch. Use `git log` to check this out.

Comment: This is why when I test something I always use a name like try-this-out. Hardly anyone already has, e.g., a branch named "try-this-out."

Comment: The new branch I made was not TEST. I wondered why the instructions didn't seem to make a branch, at least, it didn't show up in `git branch`. Why would it require --force when it is a new branch? The linked tutorials didn't mention anything about --force.

Comment: As long as you have no commit in a branch, it theoretically don't exist. Have you made sure you have at least an initial commit in your new branch?

Comment: It showed an 'initial commit', and running `git commit` showed initial commit.